# Can't Use the Notch Area in Xamarin.Forms After Setting My MainPage as NavigationPage

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my project I want to use the notch area in mobile devices with a notch so ı added this code

**MainActivity.cs file**:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);


        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        Window.Attributes.LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode = LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode.ShortEdges;
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutInOverscan);

        LoadApplication(new App());
 }
```

The whole code of MainActivity.cs file is:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace GreenPath.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "GreenPath", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = 
true,ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        Window.Attributes.LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode = LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode.ShortEdges;
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutInOverscan);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
}
```

This methoded worked and I contiuned to develop my project but after adding another page to my project and setting the MainPage as a NavigationPage the visiual that I disere disapeared.

**App.xaml.cs file:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace GreenPath
 {
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The method will remove the status bar . When you set the MainPage as NavigationPage , the Navigation Bar will on the top of screen without status bar . So what is your problem ? You could share the screen shot of the effect on your device and the result that you want to achieve .

Comment: I did a lot of work after so I can't take a screenshot of the result that I wanna achieve but I use this image as reference. I want my app to be like the upper picture but it is like in the bottom picture. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/ANnhwZwFX8cj7c30D8xhNodjQXm_NIEG5y6HwRdDw_wpBTKRblqBfep-bZQje3cvRZDMt5wMyuXJro3U7umaC_Cj2D2nZqYhWmqXBziy4AVhZAq7Uycpdg8xrHrR-gX7oeWs8uNndss1m8UO5g

Answer (score 0):

In your case , you could set the **BackgroundColor** of **StatusBar** to White directly in **OnCreate** .

We could also set the value of **BackgroundColor** in runtime if some page has different navigation bar .

You could use **DependencyService** .

#### in share project , define the interface

```
public interface IStatusBarColor
{
    void SetColoredStatusBar(string color);

}
```

#### in Android

Firstly , install the plugin **CurrentActivity** from nuegt , check https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using App24.Droid;
using App24;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SetStatusBarColorImplemention))]
namespace App24.Droid
{
    public class SetStatusBarColorImplemention : IStatusBarColor
    {
        public SetStatusBarColorImplemention()
        {
        }

        public void SetColoredStatusBar(string color)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    var currentWindow = GetCurrentWindow();
                    currentWindow.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = 0;
                    currentWindow.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(color));
                });
            }
        }

        Window GetCurrentWindow()
        {
            var window = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window;

            window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);

            window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

            return window;
        }
    }
}
```

Now invoked the line as you want .

```
DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarColor>().SetColoredStatusBar("#xxx");  // set the color with the same as navigation bar .
```

Comment: But I don't want the status bar to be in the same color, I want to display content in there.

Comment: Remove the line  `Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);`

Comment: It happend after a set the page as a navigation page.